# TypeScript Interface typing with exhaustive enum check

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a enum and I let each value of the enum as a key in my interface whose value is specific to the key.

Example:

```js
enum Fruits {
  Apple = "Apple",
  Banana = "Banana",
}

// EDIT: These slicers can have completely different shapes.
interface AppleSlicer { foo: () => string }
interface BananaSlicer { bar: () => number }

interface FruitSlicers {
  [Fruits.Apple]: AppleSlicer,
  [Fruits.Banana]: BananSlicer,
}
```

This works well, but I want have similar code in several places and I want them to give me compile errors when there's a new entry in the enum. Currently, this doesn't do any exhaustive check, so it does not. Is it possible to achieve that with TypeScript?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to make use of the [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type), which works great with enums.

Something like:

```
enum Fruits {
  Apple = 'Apple',
  Banana = 'Banana',
}

type Slicer = Function; // Quick example case

type FruitSlicers = Record<Fruits, Slicer>; // <- Ensures every enum value is a key

const fruitSlicers: FruitSlicers = {
  [Fruits.Apple]: () => {},
  [Fruits.Banana]: () => {},
};
```

Now if I add another `Fruit`:

```
enum Fruits {
  Apple = 'Apple',
  Banana = 'Banana',
  Cherry = 'Cherry',
}
```

I get:

```
Property 'Cherry' is missing in type '{ Apple: () => void; Banana: () => void; }' but required in type 'FruitSlicers'
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention this, but I can't really use a `Record` since `AppleSlicer` and `BananaSlicer` can have completely different shapes. If I use `Record`, then I have two problems. 1) I'll need to list every slice as possible types, i.e. `Record<string, AppleSlicer | BananaSlicer>`. 2) I want `Apple` to map to `AppleSlicer` only, but in your example, `fruitSlicers` can have  `BananaSlicer` assigned to `Apple` and vice versa.

Comment: Yes - undoubtedly a problem - I don't know of a way to say `Record<Fruit, Slicer<Fruit>>` and enforce that each key and value "line up" in terms of the `Fruit` instance they are talking about ...

Comment: if there is a pattern that the interfaces for each fruit would have then we could maybe create a helper type, but without that knowledge it's a little harder to know.

Answer (score 3):

For this you will need type compatibility checks. My recommended library for this is `ts-expect`: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-expect

Here is a complete sample (I've inlined `expectType` and `TypeOf` from ts-expect):

```
export const expectType = <Type>(value: Type): void => void 0;
export type TypeOf<Target, Value> = Exclude<Value, Target> extends never
  ? true
  : false;

type AppleSlicer = { apples: number }
type BananaSlicer = { bananas: number }

enum Fruits {
  Apple = "Apple",
  Banana = "Banana",
}

type FruitSlicersComplete = {
  [Fruits.Apple]: AppleSlicer,
  [Fruits.Banana]: BananaSlicer,
}
type FruitSlicersIncomplete = {
  [Fruits.Apple]: AppleSlicer,
  // [Fruits.Banana]: BananaSlicer,
}

type FruitSlicersExhaustive = {[key in Fruits]: any}

expectType<TypeOf<FruitSlicersExhaustive,FruitSlicersComplete>>(true); // Success ✅
expectType<TypeOf<FruitSlicersExhaustive,FruitSlicersIncomplete>>(true); // Error ❌
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) to constrain the input parameter type so that that it must include all of the keys in the string enum, and also all of the entries in the interface:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=28&ssc=10&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFygbwLACgpQIIAOBANsFALxQDkhJwVANNrgEICGIHbF17nnjZlADycDgHMylKqIn0mWAL7ZsiEMmBwAZmwDGZWqQDKxRPrjooWgPbWAXFAAUASgoA+KAGdkcNeKjKWGoa2npkfFwmZpqWAEZscA4u7lDgELExgarqmjr6sAgoUeae6EIA2vBIyAB0hsAAug71xZoA3BVVKDURnE1QvWytcB1KKlhaYCC6yIjWIFC6cMBsGsOlADwAKlDAAB4aIAAmpQBKwLrWcEcbXcgMUFMA1iDWAO4gHgBkBdXrbo4AG5sYhgYAOLbOCFlHBQZbIMBwBbA0HAUZZLCXEDeLymEoARh4SxWazxmk8jkwsPqDjQVlsSVc5A8VDYRFIVACClYXE4tKg8USTiZHkJigUimcbSgAHoZVAAKJwOBXJwAJgAzAAWACsznGWJxnjJcE8aqJy1WwHWlKENMsNnswpSrPZ9C5QkG-MFjJSYu5IjEIEkDior1QaigyAAFmRgrkwg9PNZFhwBWQOABPKAosGCJRS2Xy6xPbBAA)

```ts
enum Fruit {
  Apple = 'Apple',
  Banana = 'Banana',
  Orange = 'Orange',
}

interface AppleSlicer { foo: () => string }
interface BananaSlicer { bar: () => number }

interface FruitSlicers {
  [Fruit.Apple]: AppleSlicer;
  [Fruit.Banana]: BananaSlicer;
}

function createSlicers <T extends Record<Fruit, unknown> & FruitSlicers>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}

const slicers1 = createSlicers({
  Apple: { foo: () => 'apple' },
  Banana: { bar: () => 1 },
}); // Error (2345)

const slicers2 = createSlicers({
  Apple: { foo: () => 'apple' },
  Banana: { bar: () => 1 },
  Orange: 'not in the interface, so can be any value',
}); // ok
```