Required interface keys
Is there any way in TypeScript to require an interface to implement all members from for example an enum?
Example:
enum Cars {
  volvo = 1,
  audi = 2,
  bmw = 4,
}

interface CarManufacturerCountry {
  [Cars.volvo]: 'Sweden';
  [Cars.audi]: 'Germany';
}

I'd like CarManufacturerCountry here to give some type error since it does not include [Cars.bmw].
I tried:
interface CarManufacturerCountry extends Record<Cars, string> {
  [Cars.volvo]: 'Sweden';
  [Cars.audi]: 'Germany';
}

but that does not seem to work.

{ [key in Cars]: string }? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44243060/3001761

Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/70689566/3001761
